# Can't resize image with Pica in Vue CLI application

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js, image-resizing

I want to resize image with Pica before uploading it to the server. I use `vue-upload-component` with this code https://github.com/lian-yue/vue-upload-component/blob/master/docs/views/examples/Avatar.vue and everything works fine without the Pica.

I overwrite the `inputFilter()` method to this:

```
inputFilter(newFile, oldFile, prevent) {
  if (newFile && !oldFile) {
    if (!/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|webp)$/i.test(newFile.name)) {
      this.alert("Your choice is not a picture");
      return prevent();
    }
  }

  if (newFile && (!oldFile || newFile.file !== oldFile.file)) {
    newFile.url = "";
    let URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    if (URL && URL.createObjectURL) {
      newFile.url = URL.createObjectURL(newFile.file);
    }
  }

  const pica = Pica();
  const resizedCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  resizedCanvas.height = 100;
  resizedCanvas.width = 100;

  console.log(resizedCanvas);
  console.log(newFile.file);

  pica
    .resize(newFile.file, resizedCanvas)
    .then(result => console.log("resize done!"))
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("got error..");
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

and I see this in the console:

```
AvatarUpload.vue?df5a:178 <canvas height=​"100" width=​"100">​
AvatarUpload.vue?df5a:179 File {name: "img-913965899011452289.jpg", lastModified: 1473514866000, lastModifiedDate: Sat Sep 10 2016 15:41:06 GMT+0200 (czas środkowoeuropejski letni), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 179941, …}
AvatarUpload.vue?df5a:185 got error..
AvatarUpload.vue?df5a:186 TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    at _iterableToArrayLimit (pica.js?824b:1636)
    at _slicedToArray (pica.js?824b:1632)
    at processStages (pica.js?824b:2126)
    at eval (pica.js?824b:2157)
```

I also added `vue.config.js` to my project:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        pica: "pica/dist/pica.js"
      }
    }
  }
};
```

How to make the Pica works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I misunderstood the Pica's API. Instead of the File object, I should use the `<img src="" />` tag.

Working example:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img
      src="@/assets/logo.png"
      ref="imgSrc"
    />
    <img ref="imgResult" />
    <button @click="compress">Compress!</button>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Pica from "pica";
export default {
  methods: {
    compress() {
      const pica = Pica();

      const resizedCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      resizedCanvas.height = 100;
      resizedCanvas.width = 100;

      pica
        .resize(this.$refs.imgSrc, resizedCanvas)
        .then(result => {
          console.log("resize done!");
          this.$refs.imgResult.src = result.toDataURL();
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("got error..");
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```